# AWS ECS CLI Doesn't Attach EC2 Instance To Cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli, amazon-ecs

I have some docker containers, and I'm trying to launch them on AWS ECS using the ECS CLI.

These are my commands:

`ecs-cli configure --cluster abc --default-launch-type FARGATE --config-name abc-conf --region eu-west-1`

`ecs-cli configure profile --access-key xxx --secret-key xxx --profile-name abc-profile`

`ecs-cli up --security-group sg-094607105993d0351 --vpc vpc-0479323e6e7107b74 --subnets subnet-009eb5c6e08b7dbf0,subnet-0e1c2846b268b170a --keypair abc-key --capability-iam --size 1 --instance-type t2.small --cluster-config abc-conf --ecs-profile abc-profile --region eu-west-1 --force`

`ecs-cli compose up --create-log-groups --cluster-config abc-conf --ecs-profile abc-profile --create-log-groups`

However I get

```
ERRO[0001] Error running tasks                           error="InvalidParameterException:     No Container Instances were found in your cluster." task definition=0xc00031e6a0
FATA[0001] InvalidParameterException: No Container Instances were found in your cluster.
```

The reason for this is that the `ecs-cli up` command **is bringing up an EC2**, but it is **not bringing it inside the cluster**, so the cluster has no instances.

Now this works if I don't specify my own vpc and subnets, however I have to do that as there is no other way to specify a bunch of ports to open on the cluster (there is an option that only allows you to specify one port).

**So why is ecs-cli not bringing my instance inside my cluster?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally found the answer. You have to add an internet gateway to your VPC; then in the subnet that you are trying to launch your cluster, you have to add a route table entry pointing 0.0.0.0/0 to the internet gateway. It will then instantly attach the ec2 to your cluster.

Comment: I would go for a [VPC endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/vpc-endpoints.html) then. You do not want your traffic to flow outside your VPC.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you have configured your `user-data` properly on the Instance.
You should have it configured as to join the ECS cluster when they start.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "ECS_CLUSTER=MyCluster" >> /etc/ecs/ecs.config
```

More information in the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/bootstrap_container_instance.html).

Also, if you do not use an AWS ECS-Optimized AMI, more configuration might be necessary.

Comment: This isn't needed. The docs specify that the CLI already provides this user data. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/cmd-ecs-cli-up.html - search "user data"

Comment: Interesting. Thanks! Did not know about that.